# Scala - Convert String to Date in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset which I am reading into a spark RDD where date is represented in the format of "September 2016" and also "20010901" which I need to convert to a date format while creating an RDD using a Case Class

For example,
case class Bank(age: Integer, job: String, marital: String, education: String, BirthDate: "**20010901**", FiscalMonth: "**September 2016**")

How do I convert the "BirthDate" and "FiscalMonth" to a Date format recognizable to Scala as a Date where the Date might be of either format?

I need to later pull this into spark sql and run a few queries on it.

Comment: You can do a :`val format1=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")` and `val format2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy")` and then use pattern matching or a regex to find the suitable format. The actual conversion can be done with `format.parse(ds:String):Date` which will give you a good old `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to go:

```
case class Person(
               name:String,
               job:String,
               marital:String,
               birthDate:java.util.Date, 
               fiscalMonth:java.util.Date)

object Person {
  def converter(dt:String):java.util.Date = dt match {
    case x if x matches "\\d{8}" => (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd",java.util.Locale.US)).parse(x)
    case x if x matches "\\w+\\s\\d{4}" => (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy", java.util.Locale.US)).parse(x)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
  }

  def apply(a:String,b:String,c:String,d:String,e:String) = new Person(
     a,b,c,converter(d),converter(e)
  )
}

val p = Person("john","clerk","married","20121111","September 2008")
```

which will produce:

```
p: Person = Person(john,clerk,married,Sun Nov 11 00:00:00  GMT 2012,Mon Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT 2008)
```

and avoids the uncomfortable implicit conversion def from `String` to `java.util.Date`. The problem with this method is you will probably need to implement all possible Date and String combinations for the last two parameters. [There are ways to avoid this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017583/implicit-conversions-in-the-context-of-a-case-class-constructor). But I think this should work in your case.