# Implicit conversion not working with type-safe builder pattern

Tags: scala, dsl, type-inference, implicit-conversion

I am using the Scala type-safe builder pattern for a simple rest request.  This works great as a fluent api.

```
sealed abstract class Method(name: String)

case object GET extends Method("GET")
case object POST extends Method("POST")

abstract class TRUE
abstract class FALSE

case class Builder[HasMethod, HasUri](
  method: Option[Method],
  uri: Option[String]) {

  def withMethod(method: Method): Builder[TRUE, HasUri] = copy(method = Some(method))
  def withUri(uri: String): Builder[HasMethod, TRUE] = copy(uri = Some(uri))
}

implicit val init: Builder[FALSE, FALSE] = Builder[FALSE, FALSE](None, None)

//Fluent examples
val b1: Builder[TRUE, FALSE] = init.withMethod(GET)
val b2: Builder[TRUE, TRUE] = init.withMethod(GET).withUri("bar")
```

I would like to make this more DSL-like by allowing a `Method` instance be converted into a `Builder` instance, However when I add try to implicitly include the `init` builder the combination of implicit conversion and type parameters confuse the compiler.

```
implicit def toMethod[HasUri](m: Method)
  (implicit builder: Builder[_, HasUri]): Builder[TRUE, HasUri] = builder.withMethod(m)

// ** ERROR **: could not find implicit value for parameter builder: 
//              Builder[_, HasUri]  
val b3: Builder[TRUE, TRUE] = GET withUri "foo"

// However the implicit parameter is discovered fine when function is called directly
val b4: Builder[TRUE, FALSE] = toMethod(GET)
val b5: Builder[TRUE, TRUE] = toMethod(GET) withUri "foo"
```

All lines compile except b3.  When the `toMethod` function is called explicitly the builder parameter can be found implicitly.  Also if I remove the generic arguments (and the type-safety) the code works as expected.

Is this a limitation in scala's implicit conversions?  Or am I missing the correct syntax to achieve this?

I want to discover the initial builder instance implicitly to enable users to provide their own initial builder with default values for some of the builder's fields.

**Updated**

I have left some of the code out to keep the example simple, since it is just the implicit conversion that I am trying to fix.

The type-safe builder pattern is outlined very well here: http://blog.rafaelferreira.net/2008/07/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-scala.html

Afterwards you can only call the `build` method once the `Builder` has a method and a uri.

The reason that I want to discover the builder as an implicit parameter is to support the following case in the DSL.

```
url("http://api.service.org/person") apply { implicit b =>
  GET assert(Ok and ValidJson)
  GET / "john.doe" assert(NotFound)
  POST body johnDoeData assert(Ok)
  GET / "john.doe" assert(Ok and bodyIs(johnDoeData))
}
```

In these cases

1. A new builder is created with the specified uri by `url`
2. This is then reused in side the closure as `implicit b =>`
3. The `assert` method is only available because the uri and the method have been specified
4. The `/` appends to the current uri, this is only available because the builder has a uri specified.

Another example where method and uri are specified

```
GET url("http://api.service.org/secure/person") apply { implicit b =>
  auth basic("harry", "password") assert(Ok and ValidJson)
  auth basic("sally", "password") assert(PermissionDenied)
}
```

Comment: You might want to give this a look and see if it sheds light on what's going on with your implicit function that has an implicit param. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080406/implicit-parameters-in-implicit-conversions

Comment: I would rethink the design. You are duplicating information in a strange way—on the one hand you have a type constructor parameter indicating whether the builder has a method or a url at compile time, at the same time you have options which can only be solved at runtime. The question is, what do you want to achieve (where should the types be checked)? If you go with the type parameters, make subclasses that carry the method and the url (and not options). Finally, you want to elevate a method to a builder. There is no need to check for an existing `HasUri` type, it should always be `FALSE`?

Comment: @cmbaxter, thanks, I will try compiling my code with those debug options to see if it sheds any light.

Comment: @0__, You are correct that I am duplicating the runtime state of the options with phantom types.  This is to get the compiler to track which options are set and when the builder can be used to execute a request.  I am not modelling this as traits and subclasses because of the combinatorial explosion that occurs as you try to track more fields and different options (some java fluent apis do this, while the api is nice to use the code behind it is hideous).  I have updated my question to show the kind of DSLs I am trying to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code now works as-is in Scala 2.11, however it does not work in Scala 2.10 (which I was using to write this original code).

I was looking for a reason why this might be the case and can only see find this bug in the scala-lang's jira.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3346

I have tried a number of methods to resolve this in Scala 2.10 but could not.  These included @Edmondo1984 's suggestion and limiting the `HasMethod` and `HasUri` parameters as below:

```
case object GET extends Method("GET")
case object POST extends Method("POST")

sealed trait TBool
trait TTrue extends TBool
trait TFalse extends TBool

case class Builder[HasMethod <: TBool, HasUri <: TBool](method: Option[Method],
                                                        uri: Option[String]) {

  def withMethod(method: Method): Builder[TTrue, HasUri] = copy(method = Some(method))
  def withUri(uri: String): Builder[HasMethod, TTrue] = copy(uri = Some(uri))
}

object Builder {
  implicit val init: Builder[TFalse, TFalse] = Builder[TFalse, TFalse](None, None)

  // Example build method
  implicit class CanExecute(builder: Builder[TTrue, TTrue]) {
    def execute(): String = s"Build(${builder.method} ${builder.uri}"
  }
}


//Fluent examples
val b1: Builder[TTrue, TFalse] = init.withMethod(GET)
val b2: Builder[TTrue, TTrue] = init.withMethod(GET).withUri("bar")


implicit def toMethod[HasUri <: TBool](m: Method)
                                      (implicit builder: Builder[_, HasUri]): Builder[TTrue, HasUri] = builder.withMethod(m)

// ** ERROR **: could not find implicit value for parameter builder:
//              Builder[_, HasUri]
// ** BUT ** Works in Scala 2.11
val b3: Builder[TTrue, TTrue] = GET withUri "foo"

GET withUri "foo" execute ()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that your implicit resolution problem do not come from any limitation in the Scala type system, but it depends on the existential type you specify here:

```
implicit def toMethod[HasUri](m: Method)
  (implicit builder: Builder[_, HasUri]): Builder[TRUE, HasUri] = builder.withMethod(m)
```

If I am not wrong, the existential type is treated as a Nothing in this case. Nothing is a subclass of every possible Scala class, so that your method becomes in fact:

```
implicit def toMethod[HasUri](m: Method)
  (implicit builder: Builder[Nothing, HasUri]): Builder[TRUE, HasUri] = builder.withMethod(m)
```

Scala will then look in the current scope to find a subclass of Builder[Nothing,HasUri] to provide to your method and there is no class which can match the required type except Builder[Nothing,HasUri], because your builder class is invariant, i.e. a `Builder[A,B]<:<Builder[C,D]` iff `A=:=C & B=:=D`

You have therefore two options:

- Add a parameter to the signature, toMethod[HasUri] becomes toMethod[A,HasUri]
- Exploit Scala correct implementation of type variances

Since you want to enforce that your Builder[A,HasUri] is a subclass of Builder[Nothing,HasUri] and

```
Nothing <:< A for any A
```

you want to enforce that `Builder[A,HasUri] <:< Builder[B,HasUri]` iff `B<:<A` i.e. Builder is controvariant in its first type parameter. You enforce controvariance by putting a - simbol in front of the type:

`Builder[-HasMethod, HasUri]` is controvariant in HasMethod and invariant in HasUri

---

**Conclusion**

Type systems are powerful, but it's not mandatory to use complex patterns even for simple tasks:

- HasUri is not inferred from m, as it is a type parameter from the method toMethod
- HasMethod is not inferred, because you erase it using the _

What is the point of having an implicit parameter with two generics arguments if the arguments are not involved in your resolution ? I would simply write:

```
case class DefaultBuilder(m:Method) extends Builder[True,HasUri]
```

When you end up with these kind of situations, as someone has already said, it's because your design is wrong for the problem. Can you explain why the builder has to be implicit in toMethod?

```
implicit def toMethod(m:Method) = DefaultBuilder(m)
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer.  I will try out your suggestions this evening.

Regarding:
What is the point of having an implicit parameter with two generics arguments if the arguments are not involved in your resolution ?

The implicit parameter is used to pickup the current default builder in a DSL.  The generics are capturing the state of the builder, `build()` is only available on `Builder[TRUE, TRUE]`.  The `toMethod` creates a new builder, by adding the method to the current a default.  This default might or might not have a method and url set, the new one will have method set.

Comment: Then the good idea is to have a BuildingScope implicit with a defaultBuilder to be resolved